# How to delete duplicate rows in wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, observablecollection

Hi guys I am using Observable collection to store values in wpf datagrid but I want to delete duplicate rows automatically. Can anyone help me out. I have tried following way but didn't succeed. I am using MVVM.

My code :

```
public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; }


vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>();

void AddVlans()
{
    if ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanName)) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanID) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP1) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP2) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP3) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(VlanIP4) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedVlanPort))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill the empty fields", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Add vlan");
        var serial = new VLANSPropertyClass();
        serial.S_No = vlan.Count + 1;

        serial.vname = VlanName;

        serial.vid = VlanID;

        serial.ip = VlanIP1 + "." + VlanIP2 + "." + VlanIP3 + "." + VlanIP4;

        serial.mask = Vlanmask1 + "." + Vlanmask2 + "." + Vlanmask3 + "." + Vlanmask4;

        serial.vports = SelectedVlanPort;




        if (itemexists())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value already present");
        }
        else
        {

            vlan.Add(serial);
        }
    }
}





bool itemexists()
{

    var item = new VLANSPropertyClass();
    return
            (item.vname == VlanName) &&
            (item.ip == VlanIP1 + "." + VlanIP2 + "." + VlanIP3 + "." + VlanIP4) &&
            (item.vname == VlanName) &&
            (item.vports == SelectedVlanPort);
}
```

The above methods is adding rows but it's not deleting duplicate rows automatically .Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Why don't you validate first if the row already exists before adding the new one?

Comment: @sexta13...can you please elaborate ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my comment...I didn't see correctly your code.

Your problem is in your boolitemexists.

Try this:

```
if (vlan.FirstOrDefault( YOUR_CONDITIONS) ==null)
return false;
else return true;
```

YOUR_CONDITIONS I think must be something like:

x=>x.vname == serial.name && .....

Your boolexistsitem should receive the serial as parameter.

Regards,

=========NEW EDIT

```
    bool itemexists(VLANSPropertyClass serial){        
    if(vlan.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.vname ==serial.vname && serial.ip==x.ip && x.vports==serial.vports) == null)
    return false;
    else return true;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LinQ` [`Enumerable.Distinct<TSource>` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove duplicate items from a collection. Try something like this:

```
vlan = GetSomeData(); // Fill with data however you want
vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>(vlan.Distinct());
```

This could even be shortened to:

```
vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>(GetSomeData().Distinct());
```

This will only work to remove exact duplicates objects though... that is, objects that share the same reference. If you just want to remove objects that have the same property values, then you could use the overloaded [`Enumerable.Distinct<TSource>` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter.  Of course, you'd need to implement the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface to make that work correctly.